# what are the valid sanitizer suppression strings for gcc?

Tags: gcc, address-sanitizer, sanitizer, thread-sanitizer, leak-sanitizer

When using sanitizers with gcc one can provide a list of exceptions/suppressions to deal with false positives and such.

the suppression file format is poorly documented.

Each suppression is of the form

```
name_of_check:path_or_name
```

What are the valid values for `name_of_check`?

Comment: Related question: How does one specify the function name? e.g. with a report like `SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: stack-use-after-scope deps/include/yaml-cpp/node/impl.h:291 in YAML::Node::begin()`, do I use `YAML::Node::begin` as the name? clearly not, as it does not suppress it.

Comment: @oarfish - feel free to ask that question and I'll try to answer!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I resorted to grabbing the values from the source code. These are based on gcc 10.1:

- `ubsan`/`undefined` - see `libsanitizer/ubsan/ubsan_checks.inc`

  - `undefined`
  - `null`
  - `pointer-overflow`
  - `alignment`
  - `object-size`
  - `signed-integer-overflow`
  - `unsigned-integer-overflow`
  - `integer-divide-by-zero`
  - `float-divide-by-zero`
  - `invalid-builtin-use`
  - `implicit-unsigned-integer-truncation`
  - `implicit-signed-integer-truncation`
  - `implicit-integer-sign-change`
  - `shift-base`
  - `shift-exponent`
  - `bounds`
  - `unreachable`
  - `return`
  - `vla-bound`
  - `float-cast-overflow`
  - `bool`
  - `enum`
  - `function`
  - `returns-nonnull-attribute`
  - `nonnull-attribute`
  - `vptr`
  - `cfi`
- `asan`/`address` - see `libsanitizer/asan/asan_suppressions.cpp`

  - `interceptor_name`
  - `interceptor_via_fun`
  - `interceptor_via_lib`
  - `odr_violation`
- `lsan`/`leak` - see `libsanitizer/lsan/lsan_common.cpp`

  - `leak`
- `tsan`/`thread` - see `libsanitizer/tsan/tsan_suppressions.h`

  - `none`
  - `race`
  - `race_top`
  - `mutex`
  - `thread`
  - `signal`
  - `called_from_lib`
  - `deadlock`